# Databricks Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '``' given input columns:

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

I'm not sure if I'm in the correct group for this question.
Any I have created the following sql code in Databricks, however I'm getting the error message;

> Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: cannot resolve
>   '`a.COUNTRY_ID`' given input columns:
>   [a."PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT";"COUNTRY_ID";"CDC_TYPE",
>   b."PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT";"COUNTRY_ID";"CDC_TYPE"]; line 7 pos 7;

I know the code works as I have successfully run the code on my SQL Server
The code is as follows:

```
tabled = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/dbo_tabled.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
tablee = spark.read.csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/dbo_tablee.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
tabled.createOrReplaceTempView('tabled') 
tablee.createOrReplaceTempView('tablee')
%sql
; with cmn as 
  ( SELECT a.CDC_TYPE,
           a. PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT, --Add these also in CTE result set 
           a.COUNTRY_ID --Add these also in CTE result set 
    FROM  tabled  a 
    INNER JOIN tablee b 
    ON a.COUNTRY_ID = b.COUNTRY_ID 
    AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT 
    AND a.CDC_TYPE = 'U'
    )
 SELECT 1 AS is_deleted, 
        a.* 
 FROM  tabled  a 
 INNER JOIN cmn 
 ON a.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and  a.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID 
 AND a.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 0 AS is_deleted, 
        b.* 
 FROM tablee  b 
 INNER JOIN cmn 
 ON b.CDC_TYPE = cmn.CDC_TYPE 
 and b.COUNTRY_ID = cmn.COUNTRY_ID 
 AND b.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT = cmn.PK_LOYALTYACCOUNT
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, 
       a.* 
FROM   tabled a 
WHERE  a.CDC_TYPE = 'N' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL, 
       b.* 
FROM   tablee b 
WHERE  b.CDC_TYPE = 'N'
```

when I run the simple query...

example1 =

```
spark.sql("""select * from tablee""")
```

or example2 =

```
spark.sql("""select * from tabled""")
```

I get the following output, so I know the tables are there

[image: output]

Any suggestions will be well received.

Comment: What error (if any) do you see for this query? `SELECT a.COUNTRY_ID  FROM  tabled  a;` Is there actually a  COUNTRY_ID field in that table?

Comment: @JonJaussi, that was good observation. When I run the command SELECT a.COUNTRY_ID FROM tabled a; I don't see the COUNTRY_ID field as you suggested. However, this is standard sql (even though its running on Databricks). And it works fine when I run the same command on my SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use semicolon delimiter while reading from csv

```
tabled = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").csv("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/dbo_tabled.csv",inferSchema=True,header=True)
```

or

```
tabled = spark.read.load("adl://carlslake.azuredatalakestore.net/testfolder/dbo_tabled.csv",
                 format="csv", sep=";", inferSchema="true", header="true")
```

**ref:** https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#manually-specifying-options

Answer (score 0):

The columns were not being identified properly since the delimiter used was a semicolon(;) and the job was looking for commas. Problem solved